# How to restore state while changing window.location.href

Tags: javascript

After a user enters credentials on the login page, a post request is sent to the web server, which sends a cookie (if successful). On the client side, simultaneously, write the user details to my global redux store. On successful authentication from the server, I call window.location.href = 'newURL'. This call reloads my app. Now the user info I stored to the global store is lost, and I am not able to display username which was enetred by the user. How can I access the user credentials?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can store those details into localStorage or sessionStorage. This is the only way for you to track the details

Comment: Please make sure your question includes a code example that is reproducible, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why would you do a refresh? It's not necessary. But let's say you do--why wouldn't the refresh include the necessary data from the server necessary to re-hydrate the store?

Comment: But when the app gets reloaded, then won't localStorage or sessionStorage be set to empty? @Think-Twice

Comment: Plenty of libraries that do a JSON diff.

Comment: @ShubhamSingla they won't be set to empty untill and unless you remove them manually

Comment: @ShubhamSingla That would defeat the purpose of local or session storage.

Comment: You could avoid using reloading the app by using e.g. `window.history.pushState()`  (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). Given you're using Redux I guess you're using React, this type of thing is managed under the covers by React Router https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Comment: @Think-Twice Thanks a lot, it works :)

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: @ShubhamSingla I added as an answer. you can upvote and accept it so that the thread can be closed

Comment: I do not see any option to accept the answer, and I tried to upvote but since I do not have any points yet, I could not. @Think-Twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments.

You need to use either localStorage or sessionStorage to keep the data alive.

For eg

```
localStorage.setItem("user", {"name": "abc"});
```

Now, though you logged out your data will be there in localStorage and you get the data using

```
localStorage.getItem("user");
```

If you want to remove then

```
localStorage.removeItem("user") or window.localStorage.removeItem('user');
```

Same applies to sessionStorage as well